# Starting a process and handling it in C++ applications

Tags: c++, linux, process, fork, pid

I am writing a c++ application(in Linux) in which I want to start another application, only once. (If its already open, than use `handle` of that one).

Also from time to time I want to provide input to the same applications. For example:

```
    class myapp():
        start second application here.
        work()
    myapp::work(){
        create input
        provide input to the started/already open second application
    }
```

So when each time an object is created for myapp, the second application is started (only if its not open already). And then pass the input each time to the application? Would that be possible? I also dont want the second application to close, unless user ends it.
I am already using pid and fork to do this. But somehow it is starting application multiple times, and neither I am able to give input to this application.

Hope this is clear enough. I know there is already many Q&A available on this but I was not able to clearly understand, hence apologies if I am asking same question again?

Thanks for the help

Comment: Is the application you want to start a command-line program or a graphical one? Is it possible to give the input you need to give via command-line arguments (many graphical applications also accept some) or do you need to interact with the application directly?

Comment: @denisw sorry for the delay. It is a graphical application ("Wireshark") and yes it accepts inputs via command-line. Something like `my_application -> STDOUT | wireshark -k -i -` will work. But I am not much expert about how to handle the same wireshark process opened? Can you please point me in right direction. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Should I be using popen for this? I never used that before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[popen](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Pipe-to-a-Subprocess.html#Pipe-to-a-Subprocess) is the right tool for this job. You pass it a command to execute, and it return you receive a C file handle (`FILE *`) which represents the pipe from your program to the second one. All data you write with this handle is directed to the second program's standard input.

Note that this is a C file handle, so you'll need to use C I/O functions such as [fprintf](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Formatted-Output-Functions.html#Formatted-Output-Functions) to write to it. Unfortunately, there is no standard way of converting a C file handle to a C++ output stream.

Here is an example of how you might use `popen`, adapted from the [example in the GNU libc manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Pipe-to-a-Subprocess.html#Pipe-to-a-Subprocess):

```
FILE *pipe = popen("wireshark -i -k", "w"); // "w" means "write mode"
if (!pipe) {
    // execution failed
    return;
}

fprintf(pipe, "Some data");
…

// When you're done with the pipe:
pclose(pipe);
```

You can make sure that the program is started only once by storing the pipe `FILE *` in a permanent variable (e.g. an object member variable) that you initialize with `NULL`. Then you can easily check if you have already started the second application with `pipe != NULL`.

Comment: Thanks a lot denise. That was really very useful and almost worked. Although I am having an error but I think thats related to the wireshark stuff. Once again thanks a lot.